# How to add attributes to an element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working on [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/78PVu/). Why am I unable to function Tooltips in Bootstrap? Here is the attributes which I need to run the tooltip:

```
rel="tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left"
```

and my code is like:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="well"></div>
</div>

<script>
  $(".well").attr("rel", "tooltip");
  $(".well").attr("data-toggle", "tooltip");
  $(".well").attr("data-placement", "top");
  $("[rel='tooltip']").tooltip();
</script>
```

I checked the the div  in the console and it looks like looks like:

```
<div class="well" rel="tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title=""> 
  
</div>
```

but the tool-tip is not functioning!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you actually add a tip, it works fine

```
$(".well").attr("title", "This is a tooltip");
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/78PVu/1/)

Comment: Thanks adeneo, I guess I know why it wasn't showing up at mine! was it because of missing the title!?